# Getting all unique elements from a pandas DataFrame column of numpy arrays of strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I have a pandas Data Frame `df` of which elements of one column `col` is a `numpy.ndarray` of `str` type. For example,

```
col
['I like tea', 'cricket ']
['basket ball', 'I like coffee', 'cricket ']
['I like tea', 'cricket ']
['basket ball', 'cricket ']
```

now I want to get number of such unique `numpy.ndarray` in the `col` to convert it into a categorical column with new column containing positive integer values for each unique `numpy.ndarray`. When I'm using `df['col'].unique` it is throwing following error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

How to find the number of unique elements for this `numpy.ndarray` column?

- edit:
  The output I'm expecting is,

  ['I like tea', 'cricket '],['basket ball', 'I like coffee', 'cricket '],['basket ball', 'cricket ']
  These are the unique lists in the column `col`. I want these to be outputed.
- edit 2:
  When I converted each list of the `col` into a tuple, I'm getting the required result. Why is this happening?

Comment: Please add the expected output of the example above

Comment: added the example output in the edit

Comment: @MonkeyDLuffy The expected output you've added is not unique

Comment: this is happening because tuple is hashable... and lists are not...

Comment: since pandas dataframe is mutable type why does its columns have to be immutable? why does df['column'].unique() requires column to  have immutable types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should convert the np arrays to hashable type..

try this:

```
df['col'].apply(tuple).unique()
```

Or if you want unique individuals that inside the lists and not lists itself:

```
df['col'].apply(tuple).explode().unique()
```

Answer (score 1):

Never knew Luffy's learning python to beat Kaido. Lol

You should try this:

```
df['col']=[list(i) for i in df['col']]
list(df['col'].value_counts().index)
```

Comment: for the example it is returning 4 instead of 3

Comment: @MonkeyDLuffy Do you need unique lists or unique elements within those lists?

Comment: unique llists in that particular column. I added the expected output

Comment: made a mistake in the edit. rectified it now.

Comment: @MonkeyDLuffy I've edited the answer,check now